# Installing compact search in the main menu?

Tags: menus

Please tell me how to install compact Search in the main menu WordPress, just as is done in the themes:
Avada,
Vantage,
Twenty Fourteen.
Or plugin UberMenu.
In the themes Avada I like most.
Site made on the themes of Avada:
http://algolux.com/news/
If I understand correctly, there is a picture when you click on that appears below the search box.
On the Internet, a little write about traveling search forms, but they require space. as the overlap menu.
And add that I fixity when scrolling menu and the like to search form is also fixed.
Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: That's just jquery click to fadein function. Fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a menu item for search icon/button and check it's ID in HTML code. Then use can use jQuery click function to show and hide search div.

For example if my menu item list (li) id is `menu-item-22` and search form container class is `search_div` then this will be the jQuery for displaying/hiding search form on click.

```
$('#menu-item-22 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.search_div').toggle();
});
```

Also, positioning of search form container will be defined in CSS.